# How to capture DTO instantiated in service method using mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito

I have service A as

```
@Service
class ServiceA {

    @Override
    public void foo(MyDto dto){};
}
```

and service B as

```
@Service
class ServiceB{

    @Override
    public void bar(){
        final MyDto myDto = new MyDto();
        serviceA.foo(myDto);
        if(myDto.check()){
            // block to test further
        }
    }
}
```

I tried following to Test service B bar method as

```
@Mock
private ServiceA serviceA
@InjectMocks
private ServiceB unit;

@Test
public void test(){
    ArgumentCaptor<MyDto> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyDto.class);
    when(serviceA.foo(captor.capture()));
    MyDto dto = captor.getValue();
    dto.setCheck(true);
    unit.bar();
}
```

"if" in service b goes into else since it's false how can I pass stub dto in service A method call , I can't user Argument captor since value can't be captured before the method invocation.
any solution other than altering the service method ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use power Mockito to achieve this. Add following to your test class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ServiceB.class})
```

And the test implementation is as follows.

```
MyDto myDto = Mockito.spy(MyDto.class);
myDto.setCheck(true);

PowerMockito.whenNew(MyDto.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(myDto);
unit.bar();
```

Here, we are creating a spy object of myDto and using powerMockito.whenNew to pass this object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with `Mockito.doAnswer()` to set the mock method behavior:

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        doAnswer(invocation -> {
            MyDto dto = invocation.getArgument(0);
            dto.setCheck(true);
            return null; // for void methods
        }).when(mockServiceA).foo(any());
        
        unit.bar();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `when` from `Mockito` for mocking external calls behaviour. For example:

```java
MyDto mockedDto = new MyDto();
mockedDto.setCheck(true);

when(serviceA.foo(Mockito.any(MyDto.class))).thenReturn(mockedDto);

unit.bar();

assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

And you can also verify it was called (after calling `unit.bar()`):

```java
verify(serviceA, times(1)).foo(any(MyDto.class));
```

**Edit**:

For the above to work the code need some changes to be a bit more testable.

For example `ServiceA` method would return `MyDto`:

```java
@Override
public MyDto foo(MyDto dto){ /* do something */ };
```

And `ServiceB` method would then be:

```java
@Override
public void bar(){
    final MyDto myDto = new MyDto();
    MyDto updatedDto = serviceA.foo(myDto);
    if(updatedDto.check()){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: this is failing at when condition: java: 'void' type not allowed here

Comment: Thanks @GauravkumarSingh for pointing that out. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in trying some of the suggestions here, but one way I handle this sort of issue is to avoid creating new instances of classes within the methods I'm testing. For example, extract the creation of your MyDto object into a separate method, create a mock for MyDto, and then and then use a spy:

Service B:

```
@Service
class ServiceB{

    @Override
    public void bar(){
        final MyDto myDto = createDto();
        serviceA.foo(myDto);
        if(myDto.check()){
            // block to test further
        }
    }

    // You don't need this annotation from Guava, but make the createDto method 
    // visible to your test
    //@VisibleForTesting
    MyDto createDto() {
       return new MyDto();
    }
}
```

Then in your test:

```
@Mock
private ServiceA serviceA

@Mock
private MyDto mockDto;

@Spy
@InjectMocks
private ServiceB underTest;

// add a @Before and reset your mocks

@Test
public void test(){

    when(mockDto.getCheck()).thenReturn(true);
    when(underTest.createDto()).thenReturn(mockDto);
          
    underTest.bar();
    // add asserts etc
}
```

Comment: Crap - sorry, I just noticed the part of your question where you ask about any solution other than altering the service method. In this case, and if it's possible, I would change the service method so you can easily test it without resorting to something like PowerMockito.